# How to call a function with an array of strings

Tags: c

I've made a function, but I'm struggling with calling it.

This is the prototype of the function:

```
char *test(int argc, char **argv);
```

I've tried calling it this way but it doesn't work :

```
int main()
{

    char tab[3][3] ={
     "Yo",
     "Hi"};

    test(2, tab);


  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. "it doesn't work" is not a useful problem statement. Please [edit] your question and be a bit more precise.

Comment: You haven't provided any details of the `test` function, just the prototype. So, what does "It doesn't work"` even mean here?

Comment: have you tried following something similar to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032225/c-passing-char-array-to-function

Comment: test expects char**, but he is passing a char*, shouldnt it be &tab

Comment: @Yamahari wouldn't work. You cannot pass a `char (*)[3]` to a `char**` parameter.

Comment: Does the function need to change the contents or not?

Comment: how I should be calling it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This way

```
char * test(int argc,const char **argv);

int main()
 {
  const char * tab[3]=
   {
    "Yo",
    "Hi",
    0
   };

  test(2,tab);

  return 0;
 }
```

or

```
char * test(int argc,char **argv);

int main()
 {
  char arg1[]="Yo";
  char arg2[]="Hi";

  char * tab[3]=
   {
    arg1,
    arg2,
    0
   };

  test(2,tab);

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: sorry I'm confused .. "char *tab[3]" what does that mean ? is it an array or a pointer

Comment: @Exdeen `char *tab[3]` declares `tab` as an array of 3 `char *`. I.e. it is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
char* test(int index, char** char2Darray)
{
    return char2Darray[index];
}

int main()
{

    char* tab[2] ={
     "Yo",
     "Hi"};

    test(1, tab);


  return (0);
}
```

I think there are two problems in your code :

- the tab what you provided has only two item
- your tab is a pointer which pointing to char[3] types and not char*

Comment: can you explain to me "char *tab[2]" is this a pointer or an array ?

Comment: Here tab is a char pointer array with 2 element. Another words tab is an array (2 elements) which can store char*.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the 2D array

```
char tab[3][3]
```

to the function `test()`, it decays to a pointer of type:

```
char (*)[3]
```

which is a pointer to an array of 3 `char` elements.

This type is not compatible with `char**` which is a pointer-to-pointer to `char`. This is the source of your problem. You need to change the function `test()` to take `char (*argv)[3]` instead of `char **argv`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at function prototype:
 `char *test(int argc, char **argv);`

`char **argv` is pointer of pointers and the variable  `char tab[3][3]` is array of arrays so they are incompatible.

You can change function prototype to:  `char *test(int argc, char argv[][SOMECONSTANT]);` or `char *test(int argc, char (*argv)[3]);`